# Add label to JSP and change label text from java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Im currently new to JSP. Tried searching for this kind of function with no luck. Also tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420392/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-label-when-a-page-is-reloaded-in-jsp-page) but it doesn't work.

can any one help me on how to declare label on jsp and change it's value from the java code. im currently getting the value from an oracle database but i have no idea on how to pass the value to the front end? I need to pass to string to a label :( any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read little about ajax http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSP page:

```
<% Example c = new Example(); %>
<label><%=c.getName()%></label>
```

Your class Example.java:

```
private String name="igarren";

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

But you should read something about ajax as @Gaurav said

Comment: funny how they downvoted my question and was put on hold when this was the answer i was looking for :(. thank you :)